# Greyscale Image Value as Translation Driver Input

Tags: animation, drivers, procedural

I have a image sequence which from frame to frame changes intensity, black to white and back again. It is uniform in the X/Y matrix of the image.

I'm trying to figure out how to sample that changing grayscale intensity/value from image (1) to supply a value as a translation driver for animation frame (1) and so on.

So as the grayscale changes from 0 > 256 frame by frame, it passes a numerical value to X/Y or Z by frame. Suggestions?